# Expect: How to split a number with no delimiter?

Tags: linux, expect

I have numbers with different digits each into variables, and I would like to write a script which split them into three variables each one using expect tcl. The first variable should contains three digits, the second always 8 digits, and the third one the remaining digits. How could I achieve that?

Ps: The available answers on the platform show how to achieve this with bash.

Numbers:

1. 345653987652
2. 87645625398784
3. 3984737645
4. 4657636359487564

Comment: Have a look at the 2nd answer of the dup

Comment: I don't see any resemblance with that question for the following reasons: first, it has underscore as a delimiter one can use to split, mine I have precised I don't have any delimiter in my numbers as I have clearly gave some examples. Secondly the second answer you are suggesting, they supposed that x was constant my numbers are not not. I don't get it.

Comment: Yes it is constant. You want to extract the first 3 characters (constant), then the 8 next (constant), then the rest (constant : start index is 8+3, until the end of the string)

Comment: @ Aserre, thank you so much, It 's now working as expected.